# How to return JSON string as JSON in Jersey?

Tags: java, json, jersey

I am using Jersey library for writing a webcservice and I have JSON data stored as strings in the database. I get this from an external source and don't know the structure except that it's valid JSON. I need to return this JSON object embedded in another JSON Object.

```
{"id": 1, "data": {the stored json object } }
```

I tried to return this structure with a POJO with a String for the inner JSON object but it get's escaped by jersey and returns as a string and not as a JSON object. How do I go about getting what I want here ?

Comment: This is not even valid JSON...

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Produces annotation on the method, using this we can return the required response type, like this:

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
```

This above annotation on your method will return the String in JSON object and the response type would be "application/json".

Answer (score 0):

When you use @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON), you would have to import

import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

But you can simply do the below code without importing the MediaType class

```
@Produces("application/json")
```